# Python dynamic function names

Tags: python, factory

I'm looking for a better way to call functions based on a variable in Python vs using if/else statements like below. Each status code has a corresponding function

```
if status == 'CONNECT':
    return connect(*args, **kwargs)
elif status == 'RAWFEED':
    return rawfeed(*args, **kwargs)
elif status == 'RAWCONFIG':
    return rawconfig(*args, **kwargs)
elif status == 'TESTFEED':
    return testfeed(*args, **kwargs)
...
```

I assume this will require some sort of factory function but unsure as to the syntax

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The canonical way to do this is to use a dictionary to emulate `switch` or `if/elif`. You will find several questions to similar problems here on SO.

Put your functions into a dictionary with your status codes as keys:

```
funcs = {
    'CONNECT': connect,
    'RAWFEED': rawfeed,
    'RAWCONFIG' : rawconfig,
    'TESTFEED': testfeed
}
funcs[status](*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: funcs['status'] will raise KeyError

Comment: I think it is a safe way, it raises an exception when `status` is an unexpected method name.

Comment: DRY rarely applies in cases like this.  The initial list of functions may have string-like names; but this often diverges into more complex relationships.

Comment: @S.Lott: the question title states 'dynamic functions names'. This is static mapping.

Comment: @goodrone: and what do you suppose it does when you use getattr? besides there's an easy way to provide default method.

Comment: This is not the canonical pythonic way for function dispatching. getattr is the canonical method in this case

Comment: I would use this method when the status variable is not external i.e. from a webform or something, or if the functions may be renamed to something other than a lowercase version of the status string - you may also argue that this is more explicit (and therefore more Pythonic). However, I would be more inclined to use the `getattr` method when the list of functions is large or changes in size.

Answer (score 38):

you might find [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=getattr#getattr) useful, I guess

```
import module
getattr(module, status.lower())(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for this example, I didn't realize getattr() also worked on modules

Answer (score 15):

assuming that these functions belong to some module:

```
import module
return getattr(module, status.lower()).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6):

it seams that you can use getattr in a slightly different (in my opinion more elegant way)

```
import math
getattr(math, 'sin')(1)
```

or if function is imported like below

```
from math import sin
```

sin is now in namespace so you can call it by

```
vars()['sin'](1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Some improvement to SilentGhost's answer:

```
globals()[status.lower()](*args, **kwargs)
```

if you want to call the function defined in the current module.

Though it looks ugly. I'd use the solution with dictionary.

Answer (score 3):

Look at this: [getattra as a function dispatcher](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/getattr.html#d0e9362)

Comment: Link is dead, decrementing score. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem previously.  Have a look at this question, I think its what you are looking for.

[Dictionary or If Statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277965/dictionary-or-if-statements-jython)

Hope this is helpful

Eef

Answer (score 0):

some change from previous one:

```
funcs = {
'CONNECT': connect,
'RAWFEED': rawfeed,
'RAWCONFIG' : rawconfig,
'TESTFEED': testfeed
}

func = funcs.get('status')
if func：
    func(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: no it doesn't. it's the same error that heikogerlach had in the beginning.

Comment: I replaced 'status' with the variable, so I suppose technically it doesn't. I'm more interested in the method than semantics