# Python: How do you call a method when you only have the string name of the method?

Tags: python, json, api, serialization

This is for use in a JSON API.
I don't want to have:

```
if method_str == 'method_1':
    method_1()

if method_str == 'method_2':
    method_2()
```

For obvious reasons this is not optimal. How would I use map strings to methods like this in a reusable way (also note that I need to pass in arguments to the called functions).

Here is an example:

INCOMING JSON:

```
{
    'method': 'say_something',
    'args': [
        135487,
        'a_465cc1'
    ]
    'kwargs': {
        'message': 'Hello World',
        'volume': 'Loud'
    }
}

# JSON would be turned into Python with Python's built in json module.
```

Resulting call:

```
# Either this
say_something(135487, 'a_465cc1', message='Hello World', volume='Loud')

# Or this (this is more preferable of course)
say_something(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680941/python-dynamic-function-names

Comment: If it's not for use in an API, than why does it mention incoming JSON and having the method name specified in the JSON object? Do you think that is so I can build a JSON string in my Python code and then pass it around to call methods?

Comment: Calling it dynamically opens you up to injection issues.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For methods of instances, use `getattr`

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...  def sayhello(self):
...   print "Hello World!"
... 
>>> m=MyClass()
>>> getattr(m,"sayhello")()
Hello World!
>>>
```

For functions you can look in the global dict

```
>>> def sayhello():
...  print "Hello World!"
... 
>>> globals().get("sayhello")()
Hello World!
```

In this case, since there is no function called `prove_riemann_hypothesis` the default function (`sayhello`) is used

```
>>> globals().get("prove_riemann_hypothesis", sayhello)()
Hello World!
```

The **problem** with this approach is that you are sharing the namespace with whatever else is in there. You might want to **guard against the json calling methods it is not supposed to**. A good way to do this is to decorate your functions like this

```
>>> json_functions={}
>>> def make_available_to_json(f):
...  json_functions[f.__name__]=f
...  return f
...
>>> @make_available_to_json
... def sayhello():
...  print "Hello World!"
...
>>> json_functions.get("sayhello")()
Hello World!
>>> json_functions["sayhello"]()
Hello World!
>>> json_functions.get("prove_riemann_hypothesis", sayhello)()
Hello World!
```

Comment: Your final solution seems to be magically calling the function. Shouldn't that be `json_functions.get("sayhello")()` or better `json_functions.get["sayhello"]()`? Is that from an actual interpreter session?

Comment: @gnibbler, why still prefer the `get` method to `[]`? The latter is the natural syntax and, if `"sayhello"` isn't valid, throws a more meaningful exception.

Comment: @Mike, I find I use get more often because I want to supply the default argument. If your use case prefers an exception, use `[]` for sure.

Comment: @gnibbler, yours would raise an exception too, just a much less useful one than doing it the normal way.

Comment: @Mike, Yeah, in this case when no default function is supplied it would indeed be silly to try to call None

Answer (score 6):

Use getattr.
For example:

```
class Test(object):
    def say_hello(self):
        print 'Hell no, world!!111'
    def test(self):
        getattr(self, 'say_hello')()
```

Comment: what about `{'method': '__init__',...`

Answer (score 6):

The clean, safe way to do this is to make a dict mapping names to functions. If these are actually methods, the best way is still to make such a dict, though `getattr` is also available. Using `globals` or `eval` is unsafe and dirty.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the functions are all global variables (they are, unless they were defined inside another functions), they can be accessed with the `globals()` function. `globals()` returns a dictionary of all global variables, including functions.

For example:

```
$ python
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Apr 16 2009, 09:17:39) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Computer, Inc. build 5250)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> def some_function():
...     print "Hello World!"
... 
>>> globals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None, 'some_function': <function some_function at 0x6326b0>, '__package__': None}
>>> globals()['some_function']()
Hello World!
```

Comment: For the given example, this could be really insecure - there is no guarantee the INCOMING_JSON is from a friendly source.  Either incorporate a function whitelist, or use Mike's solution.