# How to use pandas.DataFrame.apply with getattr function in Python

Tags: python, pandas, apply, getattr

Suppose I'd like to remove `'$'` signs from my dataframe in Pandas. And I have created a class called `TransformFunctions` so that I can use `getattr()` to invoke function from that class (the reason being that I am using another JSON file in which I will list the method names associated with columns in the data to do the processing; because JSON only accepts strings, I decided to invoke methods based on the string using a suggestion given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2203479)).

The code is as below:

```
class TransformFunctions(object):
    def remove_dollar(self, cell_str):
        return float(cell_str.replace("$", "").replace(",", ""))

data = {
    'dpt':[868, 868, 69],
    'name':['B J SANDIFORD', 'C A WIGFALL', 'A E A-AWOSOGBA'],
    'address':['  DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM', 'DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM  ', ' HRA/DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL S '],
    'ttl#':['12702', '12702', '52311'],
    'pc':[' X ',' X', 'A '],
    'sal-rate':['$5.00', '$5.00', '$51,955.00']
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
klass = TransformFunctions()
df['sal-rate'] = df['sal-rate'].apply(getattr(klass,'remove_dollar')()) ## here, I get TypeError: remove_dollar() missing 1 required positional argument: 'cell_str'
```

I'd like to know how to use `apply` from `pandas.DataFrame` to invoke methods via `getattr` if possible. Thank you in advance for your suggestions/answers!

Comment: why not use lambdas `.apply(lambda x : klass.remove_dollar(x))`

Comment: @SEDaradji As I said, I want to use string to call the method (because I want to keep the configs in a JSON file). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is `getattr` returns method `remove_dollar` and you called it inside of `apply` without parameter when you put `()` at the end of `getattr(...)`. You should do this (i.e. remove `()`):

```
df['sal-rate'] = df['sal-rate'].apply(getattr(klass,'remove_dollar'))

Out[952]:
                        address  dpt            name   pc  sal-rate   ttl#
0    DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM  868   B J SANDIFORD   X        5.0  12702
1  DEPARTMENT OF CITYWIDE ADM    868     C A WIGFALL    X       5.0  12702
2   HRA/DEPARTMENT OF SOCIAL S    69  A E A-AWOSOGBA   A    51955.0  52311
```

---

Besides, why don't you call `apply` using directly `klass.remove_dollar` such as:

```
df['sal-rate'].apply(klass.remove_dollar)

Out[955]:
0        5.0
1        5.0
2    51955.0
Name: sal-rate, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you. The first part in your answer resolves my question. But how should I call `getattr(klass, 'remove_dollar')` if I want to pass additional parameter to `remove_dollar` function? I tried `df['sal-rate'] = df['sal-rate'].apply(getattr(klass,'remove_dollar')('test additional argument'))` after modifynig `remove_dollar's` signature to be `def remove_dollar(self, cell_str, additional_arg)`. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @user1330974: you need to use `partial` from `functools` module. `partial` allows you to make a callable with pre-passed arguments. Pass all args to `partial` except one using for `apply` later. The docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html. Search for `partial`. In your case:
`from functools import partial`;   
`remove_dollar_partial = partial(getattr(klass,'remove_dollar'),  additional_arg='test additional argument')`;  
Finally, in `apply` you call `df['sal-rate'].apply(remove_dollar_partial)`

Comment: Thank you so much for the follow-up answer @Andy L.! This example will do what I need! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can wrap in with a lambda function

`df['sal-rate'].apply(lambda x: getattr(klass,'remove_dollar')(x))`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! This works, but I accepted Andy's answer below because it's a bit more extensive (and I personally prefer non-lambda approach). Hope that's okay.