# Ruby switch like idiom

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, idioms

I have recently started a project in Ruby on Rails.  I used to do all my projects before in Python but decided to give Ruby a shot.

In the projects I wrote in Python I used a nice little technique explained by the correct answer in this post:

[Dictionary or If statements, Jython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/277965/dictionary-or-if-statements-jython)

I use this technique due to Python not having a native switch function and it also get rid of big if else blocks

I have been trying to do recreate the above method in Ruby but can't seem to quite get it.

Could anyone help me out?

Comment: Ruby has a case expression. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Its more just curiosity than anything else :)

Comment: When converting code from one language to another, it's a good idea to write the new code idiomatically for the new language. In other words, take advantage of its constructs instead of brute-forcing the other languages' constructs. In this particular case, Ruby's `Object#send` will do it, but I think for code readability and maintenance you'd probably be better off using `case/when` statements. They make it easier to see what is going on, which pays off a year later when you have to add something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only need to call a method by its name stored in a string, standard Ruby way of doing it is using method [`Object#send`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send):

```
def extractTitle dom
  puts "title from #{dom}"
end

def extractMetaTags dom
  puts "metatags from #{dom}"
end

dom = 'foo'

type = 'extractTitle'
send type, dom
#=> title from foo
type = 'extractMetaTags'
send type, dom
#=> metatags from foo
```

Otherwise, you can use Ruby's [`case`](http://www.rubyist.net/~slagell/ruby/control.html) statement, as already suggested.

Comment: you don't need the #to_sym call (send accepts both Strings and Symbols)

Comment: I just wasn't sure about earlier Ruby versions. Thanks, I will update the answer now.

Answer (score 2):

While nothing prevents you from using the class-based approach, why avoid rubys `case` statement?

```
case thing
when 'something'
   do_something
when 'nothing'
   do_nothing
else
   do_fail
end
```

Comment: Am I missing something with your `method_missing`? Surely the object can never respond to `call` if it reached method_missing.

Comment: Indeed! Nice catch. Since I was defining the methods anyway the `method_missing` only ever triggered an exception. I will update to remove the redundant code example.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, there are alternative ways of doing this in Ruby, but if you are just curious then an equivalent to that Python approach in Ruby (making use of [Object#send](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000332) once you have determined the method name) would be:

```
class MyHandler
  def handle_test(arg)
    puts "handle_test called with #{arg}"
  end

  def handle_other(arg)
    puts "handle_other called with #{arg}"
  end

  def handle(type, *args)
    method_name = "handle_#{type}"
    if respond_to? method_name
      send(method_name, args)
    else
      raise "No handler method for #{type}"
    end
  end
end
```

You can then do:

```
h = MyHandler.new
h.handle 'test', 'example'
h.handle 'other', 'example'
h.handle 'missing', 'example'
```

and the output would be:

```
handle_test called with example
handle_other called with example
handle.rb:15:in `handle': No handler method for missing (RuntimeError)
        from handle.rb:23
```